# PDF Open Parameters in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am using the following to embed an inline PDF file from a protected directory using PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');<BR>
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"'); <BR>
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); <BR>
@readfile($file); <BR>
```

My question is: How do I specify open parameters to control how the doc is displayed e.g. page=5 zoom=50 as specified in:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Answer (score 0):

They'd need to be part of the URL that's loading your script. You could try putting them into the "filename" part of the disposition header, but I don't know if Reader will look for them there.

Comment: yeah, that works - i had actually tried that but it failed for a different reason (urlencode/urldecode issue) but tried again after your reply and fixed it - thanks